# Java App Engine: "appengine-web.xml does not contain a <threadsafe> element" message

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

When I tried to run a Google web app in Eclipse, I got `appengine-web.xml does not contain a <threadsafe> element` and the app didn't run (well, any new app still does not). It wasn't hard to fix (I just added this element with a `true` value in the `appengine-web.xml` file), but I didn't get this error before. What can be a reason of such an unexpected behaviour? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Google announced this in the release notes for 1.6.4 and enforced it in the latest release.

> Omitting the `<threadsafe>` directive from appengine-web.xml now results
>   in a warning. Starting with the 1.6.5 release, omitting this directive
>   will result in an error.

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkForJavaReleaseNotes

Comment: That's exactly it. The reason we did this is to make our Java users very aware that there's a big performance improvement available for many existing apps that many long-standing developers don't know about.

Comment: But even if <threadsafe> element is present this error is still thrown.:(

Comment: Can no longer use the <threadsave> tag.  See screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/55gm9ws1alpjaaq/thread_safe.png

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky it should be in appengine-web.xml. Your screenshot shows you have it on web.xml.